# How to add new /proc/sys/kernel entries?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I wanted to add  the new sysctl parameter in kernel module for the code audit.c and this parameter value should be changed during runtime.Where exactly I need to add the new sysctl code and How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ctl_table in tree hierarchy and handle it in your module.

```
static struct ctl_table sample_child_table1[] = {
{
        .ctl_name = CTL_UNNUMBERED1,
        .procname = "sample",
        .maxlen = sizeof(int),
        .mode = 0444,
        .data = &global_var,
        .proc_handler = &proc_dointvec_minmax,
        .extra1 = &min_val,
        .extra2 = &max_val,
},
{}
};

static struct ctl_table sample_parent_table[] = {
{
.ctl_name = CTL_KERN,
.procname = "kernel",
.mode = 0777,
.child = sample_child_table,
{}
},

register_sysctl_table(sample_parent_table)
```

Comment: It looks like you've grabbed this example from Vitalik Nikolyenko's sysctl pdf, and you have modified it by changing the the `.mode` assignments and some names.  This answer would be more useful if you explained each of the assignments in the two tables (for example, what is the point of `.extra1` and `.extra2`?  What is `min_val` and `max_val`?

Furthermore, I believe `.ctl_name = CTL_UNNUMBERED1` is invalid, because `CTL_UNNUMBERED1` does not exist in the kernel.  That assignment should instead be `.ctl_name = CTL_UNNUMBERED`.

Comment: @buratino: it doesn't matter from where you grab , neither it matter whether example is precisely understandable to everyone.  All that matters is " Does the answer gives a pointer to proceed and move forward". 
I don't remember from where I copied this, but I modified and enhanced for some personal interesting stuff.

Comment: It's fine if you did grab the code from somewhere.  I think it would be helpful if you linked the original source, which goes in to more detail than you have.  It is, however, important that your example will not compile for Sowndarya, as CTL_UNNUMBERED1 does not exist in the vanilla kernel.  That would be worth mentioning in your answer.